# add_months Oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I would like to add x amount of years to a timestamp variable and reassign it to the same variable, like so (but not working)

```
d_TIMESTAMP := add_months(d_TIMESTAMP,-360);
```

I get error

> Error(48,13): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following: constant exception      table long double ref    char time timestamp interval date binary national character    nchar The symbol "" was substituted for "=" to continue.

Comment: Error is not in what you posted. Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: I'm trying to +/- some years to a timestamp variable that is a parameter in the stored procedure. I have changed it slightly to : `SELECT add_months(p_TIMESTAMP,-360) INTO p_TIMESTAMP` and the error I'm getting is _"Error(50,42): PLS-00403: expression 'P_TIMESTAMP' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement "_ and  _"Error(50,54): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier"_ for `FROM DUAL`

Comment: I may have fixed this, pending test.. I was trying to modify an IN variable. Changing it to an IN/OUT removed the error. I will post the answer once I have fully test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d_TIMESTAMP` is an input variable and as such couldn't modify it in the code. Making the variable as an `IN OUT` variable fixed the issue. Like so:
`p_TIMESTAMP IN OUT` and then:
`SELECT ADD_MONTHS(p_TIMESTAMP,-360) INTO p_TIMESTAMP
FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the number of months that corresponds to the number of years you want to add. For example, if you want to add a year, you need to add 12 months. Try this.

```
d_TIMESTAMP := ADD_MONTHS(d_TIMESTAMP, 12);
```

More information on `ADD_MONTHS`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm

Comment: Thanks @alejandrogiron , but that's what I am exactly doing. Only that the number of months can also be negative, and in my case I'm subtracting 30 yrs.

Comment: I see, it should be working properly. Maybe post the whole procedure to see if something else is wrong?